# java script code in Script command in karate is not working

Tags: karate

I was using the following code in karate using script definition ,I was not able to executed

```
script(document.getElementsByClassName("LinkGroup")[1].lastChild.href")
```

But when i execute the above script in console i was getting the result

Can some one help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need quotes. Please read the docs also: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#karate-vs-the-browser

```
script("document.getElementsByClassName('LinkGroup')[1].lastChild.href")
```